# h:commandButton onclick event interrupted by button action

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf

My onclick event gets interrupted by button action (full submit). Any ideas?

An alternative would be to change the `h:commandButton` to `a4j:commandButton`, but I need a full submit in order for the button to work correctly like this.

```
<h:commandButton onclick="trackClick();" action="#{bean.print}" />
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Could you post more code and explain in detail what you expect vs your current results?

Comment: What functionality inside `trackClick()` do you need?

Comment: trackClick() sends data per Javascript to an external Webanalysis system that tracks clicks. The sending of data is asynchronous. print() opens a print page. The problem is that on clicking the button the trackClick() function tries to send data, but is interrupted by opening of the new page.

Comment: Try `a4j:commandButton` with javascript in `oncomplete`.

Comment: Hi Vasil, a4j:commandButton would be a good solution, but my action method needs a full submit, otherwise the button does nothing